# How can I prevent a user from changing their password?

Tags: password, sudo, authentication

I want to prevent a user from changing their own password. Additionally, if possible, I want to prevent them from changing it via sudo.

Comment: A good question, I look forward to seeing the answers... I haven't go a clue :)

Comment: If they can use `sudo`, then you can't prevent them from doing anything.

Comment: @psusi you have a very poor grasp of how sudo works

Comment: Probably @psusi was talking about default sudo config, i.e. the user is member of sudo group.

Comment: The only way I know of to restrict root (sudo) would be to use apparmor. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9799756&postcount=5 (you will have to modify that for your needs).

Answer (score 4):

Change the password minimum age:

```
sudo chage -m 99999 <username>
```

---

If the user is clever enough and he has sudo priviledges, you'll have a hard time trying to stop him. If you remove `passwd` permissions he could fix it running `sudo chmod u+xs /usr/bin/passwd`. If you rename `passwd` file he could fix it running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall passwd`.

I think all you could do is to give a group (or a user) the rights to run specifics commands. If you allow them to run arbitrary commands and you try to deny them running specific commands like `passwd`, `bash` or anything "harmful", that could be easily bypassed by `cp /bin/bash ~/myshell; sudo ./myshell`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a user from running the passwd command, just make it non-executable for everyone but root.

```
sudo chmod o-x /usr/bin/passwd
```

Don't forget, there are more ways to change a password other than with Terminal!

Also visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot to see if this helps

Answer (score 1):

> chmod u-s /usr/bin/passwd

might work

Answer (score 0):

You could install

ninja

but be carefully with configurating it.

When you configurate it wrong, then
you are one level deeper and may not work as admin any more 
resp. you might then be not allowed any more to use terminal/shell/konsole
as before !